# Double quotes in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to create a bash file which calls a program that expects a parameter to submitted between two double quotes.

Take a look at my file content.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ./yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --s $1 \"$2\" -c yowsup/config &
./yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --s $1 \"$2\" -c yowsup/config &
```

The echo part prints exactly the command I need, but when I comes to execute it (next line), I am messing it up.

How can I get this fixed?

Thanks!

This is how I need to call it:

```
./yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --s 9999999999 "my parameter" -c yowsup/config
```

Echo result:

./yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --s 9999999999 "my parameter" -c yowsup/config

Call result:

```
demos: error: unrecognized arguments: parameter
```

Copying and pasting echo results:

```
INFO:yowsup.demos.sendclient.layer:Message sent
```

Comment: What is the output when it tries to execute? Errors?

Comment: Can `$1` and `$2` contain blanks, wildcards or newlines? Have you tried using `-s` instead of `--s` which a short google search suggests to be an unsupported option?

Comment: What are the values of `$1` and `$2`? What is the exact argument you're trying to pass? More details are needed.

Comment: Works fine for me...

Comment: question updated with the requested information. thanks

Comment: can you use `#!/bin/bash -x`

Answer (score 0):

```
./yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --s $1 "$2" -c yowsup/config &
```

This does the trick

Answer (score 0):

You're escaping double quotes when they're not in a string. You should only escape quotes when they're in a string themselves. For example:
`yowsup-cli demos --s $1 \"$2\" -c yowsup/config`
Won't work because the strings are escaped. Use
`yowsup-cli demos --s $1 "$2" -c yowsup/config`
instead. However, with `echo`, it's good practice to put it's content in a string, like so:
`echo "./yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --s $1 \"$2\" -c yowsup/config"`
Even then, you can just use single quotes with the string so you don't need to escape:
`echo './yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --s $1 "$2" -c yowsup/config'`
Also, you don't need the `&`s. After all that, the final result is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo './yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --s $1 "$2" -c yowsup/config'
./yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --s $1 "$2" -c yowsup/config
```